# When I run the program, it shows "killed". How do I overcome this issue?

Tags: c

This is regarding pset5 speller, and below is my code. When I run it, it shows "killed" in my terminal. Moreover, when I try to debug it or try valgrind, the program just stops and exits. How do I overcome this issue?

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// TODO: Choose number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 150000;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

//Declare variables here so that they can be used in the different functions below
unsigned int HASH_INDEX;
unsigned int NO_OF_WORDS = 0;
node *CURSOR;

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    HASH_INDEX = hash(word);
    CURSOR = table[HASH_INDEX];
    do
    {
        if (strcasecmp(CURSOR->word, word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            CURSOR = CURSOR->next;
        }
    }
    while (CURSOR != NULL);

    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    // TODO: Improve this hash function
    // close address, each bucket in the hash table is a pointer
    unsigned int hash_value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
    {
        int c = tolower(word[i]);
        hash_value = hash_value + c;
    }

    hash_value = hash_value % 31;
    return hash_value;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // TODO
    // open dictionary file
    //use fopen
    //remember to check if return value is NULL, to make sure we can successfully open up the file. If can't open then return false
    FILE *d = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (d == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // read strings from file one at a time (one word in the dictionary at a time)
    //fscanf(file, "%s", word) --> %s means want to read in a string, word is char array a place we reading the word into.
    //need to keep looping this fscanf for every word in the dictionary until fscanf return EOF (once it reaches the end of file)
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    while (fscanf(d, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        // create a new node for each word, a node that contains a value and the next pointer (this helps to store each word into the hash table)
        //use malloc to store a new node
        //remember to check if return value is NULL --> check whether malloc returns NULL or not becos if malloc does not have enough memory it will return NULL and our load function should return false
        //copy word into node using strcpy --> it takes a string and copy it from one location into another location
        node *w = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (w == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(w->word, word);
            w->next = NULL;

            // hash word using the hash function to obtain a hash value
            //use the hash function defined in dictionary.c --> function takes a string and returns an index (to determine which index into the hash table we should use when inserting this node)
            HASH_INDEX = hash(word);

            // lastly, take each of those words and insert that node into the hash table at the location given by hash functon
            //recall that hash table is an array of linked lists
            //be sure to set pointers in the correct order --> point to the 2nd node first then shift the head  to  point to the new node
            if (table[HASH_INDEX] == NULL)
            {
                table[HASH_INDEX] = w;
            }
            w->next = table[HASH_INDEX];
            table[HASH_INDEX] = w;
            NO_OF_WORDS++;
        }
    }
    fclose(d);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    // TODO
    return NO_OF_WORDS;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        CURSOR = table[i];
        while (CURSOR != NULL)
        {
            node *tmp = CURSOR;
            CURSOR = CURSOR->next;
            free(tmp);
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this! Thank you in advance!

Comment: O.T. `hash_value = hash_value % 31;` Are you aware that you are using only 31 nodes but reserving space for 150000?

Comment: Without having a test setup for this, my guess is your program is being killed due to a null-pointer dereference within `check`. You get the hash index for your word, enter your `do-while` loop (since the condition is only checked *after* the body is run with this construct), and immediately dereference it. However, you don't know that `CURSOR` is non-null.

Comment: Have you tried to run it in a debugger? That will likely be able to tell you which line of code is triggering the termination. Or if the program doesn't even start in a debugger then it could be something to do with your OS/environment. For example, Mac sometimes has extra security things which get in the way during dev.